# Including Ember Addons

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember to develop my webpage. I am not using ember-cli,i just included the ember.js,handlebars.js and jquery files in my application. Now Ember cli contains lot of addons. How to include the needed addon in my application without using ember-cli ?

Comment: Basically, you can't.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @ torazaburo